# MAILX sends an email but with a blank subject and body text

Tags: email

The following command just started sending an email with a Blank Subject and Body Text.

```
mailx -s "Daily Extract" $RESULT_EMAIL < $LOG
```

`$RESULT_EMAIL` - Contains a Distribution List that has been confirmed.

`$LOG` - Contains the contents of the email that has been confirmed.

Any ideas why the email is now blank with no subject line?

This is on a PROD server that had normal patching done. Maybe the Java version? Red Hat Server version? mailx doesn't work with version XXX?

`$LOG` - Contains the text of the email. Like...`This is the body of the Email. The email verifies that you have subscribed to us...`

NEW INFORMATION Using the command line on the server, the mailx function does send an email.

The shell script is executed from Atomic Scheduler (UC4). So, UC4 is scheduled to execute the shell script at 6:00 am. The mailx command is within this shell script.

I'll work on getting the information that you have requested.

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

[[image: Results of the CAT Command found here]]

```
lsb_release -a
Command not found
```

Comment: Does the variable `LOG` contain text that you want to send as the body of the mail message, or does it contain the name of the file that contains the body of the email?  What you are doing is using `$LOG` as a filename to redirect from, into `mailx`.

Comment: It contains the Text for the Body of the Email.  So, $LOG="This is the body of the email.  The text here is what the user will see when the email is delivered."  Also, this was a shell script I inherited with the mailx statement as I have shown.  It just stopped working.

Comment: What's in the picture? Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command and use `<` followed by some string, the shell will use that string as the name of a file whose content will be redirected into the standard input stream of the command.

In other words, when you run

```bsh
mailx -s 'Daily Extract' "$RESULT_EMAIL" <"$LOG"
```

... then whatever is in the variable `LOG` will be used as a *filename*.  If that file does not exist, the mail will be sent with no message body (you should also see "No such file or directory" error message in the terminal if you run the command manually).

However, it seems that what's in `LOG` is the message body that you want to send.  In that case, we can't use a redirection like this and must instead make sure that the variable's value, `$LOG`, is passed into the standard input stream of `mailx`.

We may do that using `printf` like so:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "$LOG" | mailx -s 'Daily Extract' "$RESULT_EMAIL"
```

or, using a here-string (supported by some shells):

```bsh
mailx -s 'Daily Extract' "$RESULT_EMAIL" <<<"$LOG"
```

or, using a here-document redirection:

```bsh
mailx -s 'Daily Extract' "$RESULT_EMAIL" <<END_MESSAGE
$LOG
END_MESSAGE
```

Comment: Gotcha.  Can you tell me why the Subject is also missing?  This is in PROD so I can't just make changes to try it.  Also, when testing on a TEST server, the email is sent with a Subject and the Body.  Whatever issue we are having, it's only on the PROD server.  Just FYI, this script with the mailx statement as I have shown, has been running like that for YEARS.  Not sure how many years but over 2 years that I know of.

Comment: @user524928 If the `LOG` variable contains the message (and not the filename where the message is stored), there is no chance that the code that you show in the question would have ever worked. If you wrote `<<<"$LOG"` in place of `<"$LOG"`, then it might work depending on what shell you use (you never mention this), but `<<<` works very differently from `<` and if you have that sort of typo in your question then I can't rely on anything else being correct.

Comment: It seems to me that although the script will be generating error messages ("file not found", for example when trying to `< $LOG`) these haven't been shared with us and we'll just having to guess