# Mailx call in shell script suddenly sending blank messages

Tags: bash, java, mailx, oracle

Similar to what was reported in posting, [MAILX sends an email but with a blank subject and body text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701702/mailx-sends-an-email-but-with-a-blank-subject-and-body-text), I have an Oracle EBS 12.2 server that's using a concurrent program (java) to invoke a shell script that uses mailx to send email. The script does some operations, writing output to a file, then sends the contents of the file to a list of addresses with mailx. Until two weeks ago that was working normally, but has now changed to sending messages with no subject, no To: header, and no body.

Calling the script from the command line works fine, sending the message as expected. The mailx call in the script looks like:

`cat /tmp/file.tmp | mailx -s "Subject of message for ${TODAY}" $recipient`

In the logs of the concurrent program, I have confirmed that the contents of file.tmp are correct, that ${TODAY} evaluates correctly, and I know the $recipient is correct since I'm getting the (empty) message. I've also tried checking the ${PIPESTATUS}, which is fine, redirecting the file as input instead cat'ing, and sending a simple echo "hello" to mailx, and they all send a blank message when called from the java program, but behave normally from the linux shell.

Operating environment: EBS 12.2.8 on RHEL8. Shell is /bin/bash.

I know there's not a lot to go on here, but trying to figure out how mailx even **can** send an empty message like this, hoping it will point me to the problem.